# Provider Package and where to put my methods/logic?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to convert my code into using providers (provider package) as I think it could be more efficient, especially due to the fact that I need to update widgets through a 'Settings Page' and 'Add More Names Page' which is further down the widget tree.

However, I'm unsure where to put the bulk of my 'logic' when using providers. For example, in my original format I have two lists `names` and `games`.

```
final List<String> names = [];
  List<String> games = ["Game 1", "Game 2", "Game 3", "Game 4", "Game 5"];
```

Beforehand, I created a Text Field that would add to the list `names`.

```
TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();

TextField(
     controller: nameController,
     onSubmitted: addToList(),

addToList() {
    if (nameController.text.isNotEmpty) {
      setState(() {
        names.add(nameController.text);
      });
      nameController.clear();
    }
  }
```

Should I put this `TextField` or `addTooList` method into my `DataProvider` class as shown below as I will need to add more `names` and `games` further down the widget tree. If so how/how would you use it?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DataProvider with ChangeNotifier{
  List<String> _names;
  List<String> _games;

  DataProvider(){
    _names = [];
    _games = ["Game 1", "Game 2", "Game 3", "Game 4", "Game 5"];
  }

  // Getters - How we get these values
  List<String> get names => _names;  
  List<String> get games => _games;

  // Setters
  void setNames(List<String> names){
    _names = names;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setGames(List<String> games){
    _games = games;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Thank you! Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you would put anything that is not directly UI related in your Provider. And then do anything like modifying UI and consuming data from your Provider in the Widgets.

Another way to look at it is, "can I write less Code if it is in the Provider?" So if you are calling your function in many places, and those values get modified and used in other places, put it in the Provider.

Overall its just about making your development easier, so do whatever makes most sense, there are no strict rules.

EDIT:

Without seeing more of your code it's hard to say how I'd do it with your example. But I would guess the TextField stays in Widgets, since its a UI element. And your function looks like it should be in Provider.